# Filter only numbers (0-9) in output

Tags: powershell, filter, numbers

I have a text, for example:

```
cd123aaq54
```

and I'd like to separate only numbers in another file, so I could have

```
12354
```

in the output.

I have been trying a lot of commands like

```
Get-Content text.txt | Select-String  -Pattern '[0-9]'
```

In linux it's much easier, just

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*' text >numbers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way in PowerShell is probably to replace all non-digits:

```
@(Get-Content text.txt) -replace '\D',''
```

You can use the `Out-File` or `Set-Content` cmdlet's to output the result to a file:

```
@(Get-Content text.txt) -replace '\D','' |Out-File C:\output.txt
```

If you have many lines in your text file, you might want to take advantage of PowerShell's pipiline nature and pipe the output from `Get-Content` directly to `ForEach-Object` and perform the `-replace` operation in there:

```
Get-Content text.txt |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\D',''} |Set-Content C:\output.txt
```

Comment: Oh my god thaks!
But another problem... the document has some commas, (,)
How can i keep them?
I mean, they are prices, for example 150,36

Comment: Use character class subtraction: `-replace '[\D-[,]]',''`

Comment: Hi again! I have found powershell too slow (the script is so slow to complete and I want it in a loop.) Id like to know if you know another way to do it in classic cmd, not in powershell. Thanks again!

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoLizanaHidalgo Does the `text.txt` file have many lines?

Comment: Edit: just 1. Sorry. It have to read a text.txt and create another one only whith their numbers. I am so gratefull.

Comment: What Id like to do is: text.txt>onlynumbers.txt

Comment: Thanks again, but the problem is that I dont want to use powershell, that´s why I am looking for a command to do it in classic cmd. When I use Get-Content text.txt |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\D',''} |Set-Content C:\output.txt, cmd cant find the command get-content.